# How to access already existing cookies in angular 5 from browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cookies, angular5

I have a node app and when login is success Iam storing a token and customer id in cookies.Then on a button click Iam routing it to my angular 5 application.Now I need those two cookie values to be used in my angular 5 application.Iam able to still see those cookie values in browser but unable to access those cookies

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5wXr.png)

```
console.log("cookies",this.cookieService.get('customerid'));
```

I tried using ngx-cookie-service but using this Iam able to access newly created cookies but not existing cookies how can I access this cookie can some one help

Comment: `console.log(decodeURIComponent(document.cookie));`

Comment: I tried this but didnt worked gave me as undefined

 console.log(decodeURIComponent(document.customerid));

customerid is my cookie name

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović any other way is it possible?

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović This is not giving me all the cookies which are listed in browser

Comment: Before you claim things don't work I suggest you read the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie 
It's working perfectly as it should and will display all the cookies **which are accesible from your location**.